# Crushing Cylindrical wooden pillar

Tags: geometry

The Crushing load of a cylindrical wooden pillar varies directly as the fourth power of its diameter and inversely as the square of its height. If $K$ is the crushing load of a certain wooden pillar, what is the crushing load of a wooden pillar that has twice the diameter and half the height of the pillar with crushing load $K$.

a. $K$

b. $4K$

c. $16K$

d. $64K$.

How are you getting $2^4$ from $K$? thats what I am trying to figure out I know that $K = p* (d^4)/h^2$ and I don't see how to proceed from there.

Comment: Hint: $V \propto r^2h$, where $V$ is the volume, $r$ is the radius, $h$ is the height. What happen to $V$ when $r$ is doubled and $h$ is halved?

Comment: $V\propto \frac{r^4}{h^2}$ inverse proportional to the square of the height

Answer (score 0):

Twice the diameter multiplies $K$ by a factor $2^4=16$.

Half the height divides $K$ by a factor $\frac{1}{2^2}=\frac{1}{4}$

Eventually the Crushing factor is

$$\frac{16}{\frac{1}{4}}K=64K$$

Comment: I got it. thanks for the help